# angular-cli Path must be a string. Received undefined

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I updated `angular-cli` version and the current version I have right now is `1.0.0-beta.32.3 [1.0.0-beta.26]`. However, on running the `test` script i.e. `npm run test` it throws the following error:

`Path must be a string. Received undefined`

Found a similar issue opened a few days ago here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4815

Seems like a webpack issue to me but I can't really say. I hope this helps everyone running into the same issue.

**Update:**

```
Path must be a string. Received undefined
TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.resolve (path.js:1146:7)
    at getWebpackTestConfig (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-test.js:131:25)
    at init (/usr/lib/node_modules/angular-cli/plugins/karma.js:45:25)
    at Array.invoke (/home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Injector.get (/home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:48:43)
    at /home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:143:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Server._start (/home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:142:21)
    at Injector.invoke (/home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:75:15)
    at Server.start (/home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:103:18)
    at Promise (/home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/test.js:34:25)
    at Class.run (/home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/@angular/cli/tasks/test.js:15:16)
    at Class.run (/home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/test.js:38:25)
    at Class.<anonymous> (/home/umair/workspace/ng-portal/node_modules/@angular/cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:134:17)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

**angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.26",
    "name": "ng-portal"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
         "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {

      "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
      "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*.+(otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)"
],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": true,
      "directive": true,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": true,
      "service": true
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which path must be a string?

Comment: The last time I seen this error I was trying to load a custom environment that I hadn't put into the environments array of .angular-cli.json. Are you using custom environments in your code? EDIT - also, it could just be as simple as you've accidentally deleted the environment.test.ts file

Comment: @Sandrooco Added the complete error trace.

Comment: @peppermcknight Nope. No custom env vars.

Comment: Could you please show your `angular-cli.json`? Plus: Update your global package to match the local version.

Comment: @Sandrooco Added `angular-cli.json`

Comment: Ok first update your global install, then make sure the file is named `.angular-cli.json` not `angular-cli.json` anymore (notice the `.`!).

Comment: I don't think `.angular-cli.json` would work. The correct file name is `angular-cli.json` without the dot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, updating karma.conf.js fixed it, as explained here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4815

Replace `angular-cli` with `@angular/cli` in `karma.conf.js` and you should be good to go.